# Ruby NoMethodError (undefined method ''...' for '....:Class'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, irb

```
require_relative 'json_lookup'
require_relative 'csv_lookup'
require_relative 'error'

BASE_RATE = 'EUR'

class CurrencyExchange

  def initialize(file:, date:, from:, to:)
    @file = file
    @date = date
    @from = from
    @to = to
  end

  def rate
    lookup = find_lookup
    lookup.to_currency / lookup.from_currency
  end

  private
  def find_lookup
    case File.extname(@file)
    when ".json"
      JsonLookup.new(@file, @date, @from, @to)
    when ".csv"
      CsvLookup.new(@file, @date, @from, @to)
    else raise FileError
    end
  end
end
```

I keep on getting this error for when i run the CurrencyExchange.rate in irb so I am guessing something is going wrong with the rate method but can't figure it out as to why. But I may be missing something completely obvious... As  I am a complete beginner at Ruby, would appreciate any help :)

The traceback is as follows..

```
irb(main):003:0> CurrencyExchange.rate(Date.new(2018, 11, 22), "USD", "GBP")                                            Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `<main>'
        4: from C:/Ruby26-x64/bin/irb.cmd:31:in `load'
        3: from C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/irb-1.0.0/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from (irb):3
        1: from (irb):3:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `rate' for CurrencyExchange:Class)
```

Comment: Can you please add the full error message and the stack trace to your post? With the current title, it will be very hard to help you, because the fragment of the error message only tells that you try to call some method on some object and that that method does not exist...

Comment: @spickermann it has been added!

Comment: I would advise working through a tutorial on the fundamentals of **objects** in ruby. `CurrencyExchange#rate` is an instance method that takes no arguments, but you're trying to invoke it as a class method with arguments - hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

`rate` is an instance method in your example, but `CurrencyExchange.rate` tries to call a class method.

To solve this, initialize an instance first and call then `rate` on that instance. Furthermore, `rate` doesn't accept arguments, you need to pass the variables to the initializing method.

```
currency_exchange = CurrencyExchange.new(
  file: file, date: Date.new(2018, 11, 22), from: "USD", to: "GBP"
)
currency_exchange.rate
```

Please note that the initializer expects 4 named arguments. You will need to pass a file to the `new` method too.